# Making SOAP Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, soap

I am new to SOAP and XML. I have been through several tutorials but nothing seems to be working for me.
Below is the code I have written so far but still I am unable to get the desired results.

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://www.carrierrate.com/RateQuoteService/service.asmx?WSDL');
$params = array('quoteInfo' => '', 'quoteItems' => '');
$response = $soapclient->RateMyShipment($params);
var_dump($response);
```

Actually I am trying to find Shipment Rates. It says "User credential not valid". It looks like I can pass user credentials as

```
$params = array('ShipperUserNameWithCarrierRate' => 'myUsername', 'ShipperPasswordWithCarrierRate' => 'myPassword');
```

but I am not getting how to pass a complete array of "QuoteInfo" including ShipmentRequestDate, ShipmentOriginZip..

Please let me know what I am missing or is there an easy way to send complete SOAP request mentioned here http://www.carrierrate.com/RateQuoteService/service.asmx?op=RateMyShipment thorugh jQuery/Ajax

I can work with both either PHP or jQuery.

Your help will be greatly appriciated!

Comment: RateMyShipment() is the method defined in soap server. You have to know the type and format of the parameter from the definer of this function RateMyShipment

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more please. Do I need to pass two arrays of quoteInfo and quoteItems for all the values and call RateMyShipment function for response?

Comment: could you provide a test username and password? if your provide a username and passwod i can solve your problem i develope many soap client and servers

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `quoteInfo` and `quoteItems` should both be arrays by themselves, so `$params` becomes an array consisting of 2 arrays.
Try

```
$quoteInfo = array('ShipperUserNameWithCarrierRate' => 'myUsername',
                   'ShipperPasswordWithCarrierRate' => 'myPassword',
                   ...);
```

and

```
$quoteItem1 = array('ItemWeight' => ...,
                   'ItemHeight' => ...,
                    ...);
$quoteItems = array('QuoteItemsInfo' => array($quoteItem1, ...));
```

then

```
 $params = array('quoteInfo' => $quoteInfo, 'quoteItems' => $quoteItems);
```

The possible key/value pairs for each array are defined in the SOAP XML desription you linked.

Comment: I already tried this and here is the updated code http://pastebin.com/MpbSYEnU It shows empty array and response is Null

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with the code you pastebin'd, except maybe that `$quoteItems = array('QuoteItemsInfo' => $QuoteItemsInfo);` should actually be `$quoteItems = array('QuoteItemsInfo' => array($QuoteItemsInfo));` - sorry, but I don't think I can help you any further :-(

Answer (score 1):

First of all check http://www.carrierrate.com/RateQuoteService/service.asmx for docs on functions and here is what you want; http://www.carrierrate.com/RateQuoteService/service.asmx?op=RateMyShipment

So basically what you will need is;

```
  $params = array('ShipperUserNameWithCarrierRate'=>$username,
 'ShipperPasswordWithCarrierRate'=>$password,
 'OtherParameters' => $parameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm feeling generous, so I'll provide a solid solution to this.  I have been messing with the CarrierRate API for at least a year now, and I have managed to create a Class for it

http://pastie.org/10245578

To use this class, you must of course require it in your script, and then add the missing parameters that actually matter.

```
require('quote.php');
$quoteInfo['ShipmentOriginZip'] = 28906;
$quoteInfo['ShipmentDestinationZip'] = 30301;
$quoteInfo['ShipmentRequestDate'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 months'));

$quoteItems['FAKClass'] = 55;
$quoteItems['ItemWeight'] = 10000;
$quoteItems['ItemHeight'] = 60;
$quoteItems['ItemLength'] = 60;
$quoteItems['ItemWidth'] = 60;
$quoteItems['Pieces'] = 60;
$quoteItems['PalletCount'] = 60;

$carrierRate = new CarrierRate($quoteInfo, $quoteItems);
$carrierRate->execQuote();

if($carrierRate->hasError == false) {
    echo "<h2>Business to Business Quotes</h2>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($carrierRate->quote_responses['b'] as $k=>$q) {
        echo "<li>" . $q['carrierName'] . " @ " . $q['after_price'] . "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>";

    echo "<h2>Business to Residential Quotes</h2>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($carrierRate->quote_responses['r'] as $k=>$q) {
        echo "<li>" . $q['carrierName'] . " @ " . $q['after_price'] . "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
} else {
    echo "<pre>", print_r($carrierRate->errors), "</pre>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://www.carrierrate.com/RateQuoteService/service.asmx?WSDL');

if ($soapclient)
{
   $params = array ('quoteInfo' =>
           array (
                   "ShipperUserNameWithCarrierRate" => "username",
                   "ShipperPasswordWithCarrierRate" => "password",
                   "ShipmentRequestDate"=> "2015-01-16",
                   "ShipmentOriginZip"=> "",
                   "ShipmentDestinationZip"=> "",
                   "ShipmentPickupService" => "None",
                   "ShipmentDropoffService" => "None",
                   "ShipmentExtraService"=> "None",
                   "IsTradeShow"=> "0",
                   "IsSortnSegregate" => "0",
                   "IsInsidePickup" => "0",
                   "IsExtremeLength"=> "0",
                   "ExtremeLength"=> "",
                   "ExtremeLengthBundleCount" => "",  
                   "isInsuranceRequired" => "0",
                   "isNewItem" => "0",
                   "RequiredInsuranceAmount"=> "",
                   "NonCommercialDeliveryType"=> "None",
                   "IsProtectFromFreeze" => "0"
           ), 'quoteItems' =>
           array (
                   "FAKClass" => "",
                   "ItemWeight" => "1",
                   "ItemHeight" => "30",
                   "ItemLength" => "30",
                   "ItemWidth" => "20",
                   "PackageTypeName" => "",
                   "PackageTypeId" => "",
                   "ProductId" => "",
                   "ItemNmfc" => "",
                   "Hazardous" => "1",
                   "Pieces" => "",
                   "PieceDescription" => "",
                   "PalletCount" => ""
   ));

   $response = $soapclient->__soapCall("RateMyShipment", array ($params));
   var_dump($response);
}
```

Comment: Running your code says `SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'ShipmentRequestDate' property` I tried updating quoteInfo array with other values and the response array is still empty.

Comment: some parameters are needed such as ShipmentRequestDate for example, or ShipmentDestinationZip and ShipmentOriginZip, so try it as above and check the output.

Comment: Yes as from my previous comment I already tried passing the remaining parameters but the response array is still empty :(

Comment: Is it empty because it doesn't find anything that matches your criteria? Can you ask for some details on a valid example from "carrierrate"? I simply say that if something was wrong in the request in the first place you would get an error message and not an empty response ;)

Comment: i think that there are parameters that are mandatory and must be valid (logically), i mean the date parameter must be set, the origin and destination zip as well (can't get any shipment rates if origin and destination quotes are not set). So basically i think this is simply a valid parameter issue from this point on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked with Service Provider team ? It seems you might be missing some mandatory parameters and hence you are getting empty response, if there would have been some problem with you request object you would have got some error code in response. connect with them who has written webservice they are the right person to guide you.